# How to save an .exr file with 32 bit with python

Tags: python, image, .exr

I'd like to create a picture in blender and save it as a 32 bit exr.

```
import bpy

# in case of re-runnign this code, 
# get the old 'foo' image out of the way 
if 'foo' in bpy.data.images:
    bpy.data.images['foo'].name='bar'

#create an HDR image with name 'foo'
bpy.ops.image.new(name='foo', width=512, height=512, alpha=False, float=True)

#find the image with name 'foo'
image=bpy.data.images['foo']

# set it up for saving an exr HDR image
image.filepath_raw =  '/tmp/foo.exr'
image.file_format = 'OPEN_EXR'
# TODO here: image.save_as_32_bit=True (instead of 16)

#save image to disc
image.save()
```

The above code makes 16 bit exr according to imagemagick.
I want to use `bpy.ops.image.save_as` somehow from python, in conjuction with this code, to emulate the behaviour of `Image->Save as Image` with the option `[Float (Full)]` rather than `[Float (Half)]`

The Save as dialogue points to a thing called `ImageFormatSettings`. Where can I supply this in python?

[image: save as image dialogue]

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the color depth like this:

```
image_settings = bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings
image_settings.file_format = "OPEN_EXR"
image_setting.color_depth = '32'
```

Note that '32' is a string and not an integer/float.
Then save the image like this:

```
img = bpy.data.images['myImage'] # your image here
img.save_render("C:\\Users\\daddy\\me\\Documents\\myImage.exr") # save to desination
```

Comment: this does not work for me -> [enum '32' not found in ('8', '16')] also, the question is about how i can save the image with 32 bit, I don't think setting the color depth in the renderer will solve the problem (the image internally is already 32 bit). Please elaborate if i am wrong.

Comment: Updated answer. If you use save_render instead of ops, it will use the scene's image settings. The error you got was because it has to be set to EXR before you can access the 32 bit option(my bad).